# gitlab removes random letter from pipline

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

So I have a really strange error sometimes a letter is removed in my gitlab pipeline:

So this is a part of my `gitlab-ci.yml`:

```
- echo "Building passed"
- echo "Testing python"
- ./venv/Scripts/pytest.exe project/tests
- echo "Testing cpp"
```

Last week I had problems that the "p" was removed from pytest and the pipeline tried to execute     `- ./venv/Scripts/ytest.exe project/tests` and complained that no `ytest.exe` was found. Today I had a similar issue when the "e" was removed from `echo`:

```
$ echo "Testing python"
cho : The term 'cho' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
```

I've logged into my gitlab runner and check that the correct code is on the gitlab runner.

Running a Gitlab self hosted server v16.5.0.

Any idea what could cause this stupid error?

Answer (score 0):

In case there are some "non-printable characters" that might cause unexpected behavior, try, for testing, to simplify your commands or place them in a script which you call from the `gitlab-ci.yml`.

```bash
# create a script called test.sh
echo -e "#!/bin/bash\n\n./venv/Scripts/pytest.exe project/tests" > test.sh
chmod +x test.sh

# update gitlab-ci.yml to call the script
- ./test.sh
```